# emacs automatically open in mac

Tags: macos, emacs

I was setting up with emacs on my macbook. In order to open the emacs from command line, I was follow other's suggestion to add an emacs script to my /usr/bin.
Now I can open graphic emacs from command line, but the problem is that every time when I open the terminal, the emacs is automatic run. I don't know why this happened.
Here is the script I added:
`#!/bin/sh 
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"`
I also use `chmod +x /usr/bin/emacs` after the script was added.
Please tell me what cause the problem happens.

Comment: Did you add anything to your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I didn't add anything to the profile. It just automatically launched. I'm using zsh

Answer (score 0):

If your using the standard OS X terminal, look under preferences->profile and the shell tab and make sure there isn't something set in the run on startup option.

If your using another terminal, such as iTerm, check the profiles.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing in startup option. I tried both in my OS X terminal and iTerm and they both have this problem.

Comment: OK, given that it is happening in both, my guess would be it has to be something in your .bash_profile or possibly your .bashrc (assuming your running bash - substitute whatever the startup files are for your shell if not bash). Perhpas post these two files and we can see if there is something obvious.